# Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:io' Class: _RandomAccessFileOpsImpl@14069316)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to do log output to a file in parallel in the Dart language but I get the following error I can't read from the error at all what the error means, does anyone know a solution?

```
Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:io' Class: _RandomAccessFileOpsImpl@14069316)
#0      Isolate._spawnFunction (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:395:25)
#1      Isolate.spawn (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:375:7)
#2      _IsolateThread._startImpl (package:async_task/src/async_task_isolate.dart:457:19)
#3      _IsolateThread._start (package:async_task/src/async_task_isolate.dart:445:12)
#4      _AsyncExecutorMultiThread._catchNotFreeThread (package:async_task/src/async_task_isolate.dart:133:24)
#5      _AsyncExecutorMultiThread._catchThread (package:async_task/src/async_task_isolate.dart:125:12)
#6      _AsyncExecutorMultiThread._dispatchTask (package:async_task/src/async_task_isolate.dart:198:18)
#7      _AsyncExecutorMultiThread.execute (package:async_task/src/async_task_isolate.dart:178:7)
#8      AsyncExecutor._executeAlreadyStarted (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:566:28)
#9      AsyncExecutor.execute (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:533:14)
#10     _TaskToExecute.execute (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:695:16)
#11     AsyncExecutor._flushTasksToExecute (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:556:9)
#12     AsyncExecutor.start.<anonymous closure> (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:508:7)
#13     FutureOrExtension.then (package:async_extension/src/async_extension_base.dart:160:21)
#14     AsyncExecutor.start (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:505:29)
#15     AsyncExecutor._executeNotStarted (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:545:5)
#16     AsyncExecutor.execute (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:531:14)
#17     AsyncExecutor.executeAll.<anonymous closure> (package:async_task/src/async_task_base.dart:591:18)
#18     new _GrowableList.generate (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:136:28)
```